# 'Unable to resolve module react-native' when install react-native library

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I'm trying to create some audio and video playback. I've tried to install several library like react-native-video, react-native-video-player but it keeps throw error 'Unable to resolve module react-native-video-player from C:\Users\AHT\OneDrive\Desktop\ignite-youth\features\fuel\screens\SeriesPost.tsx: react-native-video-player could not be found within the project or in these directories:  node_modules'. I just normally import the library like this:

```
import VideoPlayer from 'react-native-video-player';
```

Any one has solution? Thank you

Comment: after installing package retry by stopping development server as well as metro bundlers.

Comment: I've it many times but still not work...

Comment: after you install `npm i react-native-video-player` you should stop those things. even if it is not working delete the `package.json.lock` file and `node_modules` folder. than install the node module `npm install`